# How to create line chart with real third coordinates?

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

I would like to generate something like 3D Line Chart in Excel. Like the following figure

[image]

but including third coordinates.

**Example**

I have a set of 2D data combied with 1D spatial data.

```
dxy = {{{0, 5.5`, 71.53`}, {0, 7.5`, 42.25`}, {0, 11.5`, 15.85`}, {0, 
     15.5`, 20.33`}, {0, 18.`, 43.555200000000006`}, {0, 
     22.833333333333332`, 24.47`}}, {{10.`, 5.5`, 48.5`}, {10.`, 7.5`,
      40.44`}, {10.`, 11.5`, 14.69`}, {10.`, 15.5`, 14.65`}, {10.`, 
     18.`, 42.9104`}, {10.`, 22.833333333333332`, 24.16`}}, {{425.`, 
     5.5`, 44.46`}, {425.`, 7.5`, 83.82`}, {425.`, 11.5`, 
     21.88`}, {425.`, 15.5`, 71.99`}, {425.`, 18.`, 63.65`}, {425.`, 
     22.833333333333332`, 45.32`}}, {{650, 5.5`, 64.52`}, {650, 7.5`, 
     65.36`}, {650, 11.5`, 20.0512`}, {650, 15.5`, 66.8`}, {650, 18.`,
      38.6984`}, {650, 22.833333333333332`, 30.3`}}, {{700, 5.5`, 
     105.49`}, {700, 7.5`, 118.6`}, {700, 11.5`, 17.1288`}, {700, 
     15.5`, 43.39`}, {700, 18.`, 29.276`}, {700, 22.833333333333332`, 
     23.18`}}, {{1300, 5.5`, 35.98`}, {1300, 7.5`, 
     59.976800000000004`}, {1300, 11.5`, 35.2768`}, {1300, 15.5`, 
     45.09`}, {1300, 18.`, 7.872800000000001`}, {1300, 
     22.833333333333332`, 7.86`}}};

ListPointPlot3D[dxy, Filling -> Bottom, 
 AxesLabel -> {"Distance", "Time", "Value"}, 
 LabelStyle -> Directive[Bold]]
```

> [image]

Almost does  what I wanted, but I cannot connect the dots by options. If I use `Line`, I have to do the coloring manually. I plan to apply the code for more different size datasets.

```
ListPlot3D[dxy]
```

Gives an empty graph.
Surprisingly, if I change the order of coordinates it works.

```
xyd = dxy /. {a_, b_, c_} -> {b, c, a}
```

> ```
> {{{5.5, 71.53, 0}, {7.5, 42.25, 0}, {11.5, 15.85, 0}, {15.5, 
>  20.33, 0}, {18., 43.5552, 0}, {22.8333, 24.47, 0}}, {{5.5, 48.5, 
>  10.}, {7.5, 40.44, 10.}, {11.5, 14.69, 10.}, {15.5, 14.65, 
>  10.}, {18., 42.9104, 10.}, {22.8333, 24.16, 10.}}, {{5.5, 44.46, 
>  425.}, {7.5, 83.82, 425.}, {11.5, 21.88, 425.}, {15.5, 71.99, 
>  425.}, {18., 63.65, 425.}, {22.8333, 45.32, 425.}}, {{5.5, 64.52, 
>  650}, {7.5, 65.36, 650}, {11.5, 20.0512, 650}, {15.5, 66.8, 
>  650}, {18., 38.6984, 650}, {22.8333, 30.3, 650}}, {{5.5, 105.49, 
>  700}, {7.5, 118.6, 700}, {11.5, 17.1288, 700}, {15.5, 43.39, 
>  700}, {18., 29.276, 700}, {22.8333, 23.18, 700}}, {{5.5, 35.98, 
>  1300}, {7.5, 59.9768, 1300}, {11.5, 35.2768, 1300}, {15.5, 45.09, 
>  1300}, {18., 7.8728, 1300}, {22.8333, 7.86, 1300}}}
> ```

```
ListPlot3D[xyd]
```

> [image]

Works, but -of course - with wrong connections.

`Dimensions[dxy] == Dimensions[xyd]` is obviously `True`, `Options[]` of the outputs are similar. I do not understand the difference.

Comment: What nobody has mentioned so far is that this chart is an absolutely terrible way of presenting quantitative information. Although the answers show very well that one can produce it in *Mathematica*, I would still avoid actually using it, if I were you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bit sneaky and likely to break with new versions, but here you go:

```
ListPointPlot3D[dxy, Filling -> Bottom, 
  AxesLabel -> {"Distance", "Time", "Value"}, 
  LabelStyle -> Directive[Bold]] /. p : _Point :> {p, Line @@ p}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Nice and compact, thanks.

Comment: Although these are lines, not planes..

Comment: @Öskå knock yourself out - ´s not far away ;-) In fact, the OP mentioned that lines would be just fine...

Comment: "_Almost does what I wanted_" Let's reach the _That's exactly what I wanted_ ;o) :D

Comment: @Öskå strict adherance to the [pareto principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_principle) here (har har, if only!).

Answer (score 10):

For *Mathematica* versions <9 use `Table[Blend["Rainbow", i], {i, 0, 1, 1/(Length@dxy - 1.)}]` instead of `Array` for colors.

**Edit:** Thanks to [Öskå](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/1356/oska) encouragement I've updated answer so now it fits OP's example well.

```
  With[{
  w = 60,
  colors = Array[Blend["Rainbow", #] &, Length@dxy, {0, 1}],
  opt = Sequence[BoxRatios -> 1, ViewVertical -> {0, 0, 1}, AxesLabel -> {x, y, z},
                 Axes -> True, ViewPoint -> {2.2, 2, 1.5}, Boxed -> False,
                 FaceGrids -> {{{-1, 0, 0}, {{}, Range[0, 120, 40]}}, {{0, -1, 0},
                               {{}, Range[0, 120, 40]}}},
                 PlotRange -> {0, All}, BaseStyle -> {Bold, 18}, ImageSize -> 400]
  },
 Grid[{{
    Graphics3D[{EdgeForm@Opacity[.33],
     Riffle[colors,
      (Polygon[Join[#, # + {w, 0, 0} & /@ Reverse@#]] & /@ Partition[#, 2, 1]) & /@ dxy]
     }, opt]
    ,
    SwatchLegend[colors, Table[StringForm["data_``", i], {i, Length@dxy}]]
    }}, BaseStyle -> {18, Bold}]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

This is not as beautiful or finessed as Kuba (though I borrowed color scheme) I post for little variant:

```
rbn[pts_, i_, opts___] := Module[{up, dn},
  up = Partition[# + {i, 0, 0} & /@ pts, 2, 1];
  dn = Partition[# - {i, 0, 0} & /@ pts, 2, 1];
  MapThread[{opts, Polygon[Join[#1, Reverse@#2]]} &, {up, dn}]
  ];
```

Example 1:

```
Manipulate[
 Graphics3D[rbn[#, inc, FaceForm[Red]] & /@ dxy, 
  BoxRatios -> {2, 2, 1}, Axes -> True], {inc, 20, 50}]
```

[image]

Example 2:

```
Graphics3D[
 MapThread[
  rbn[#1, 40, #2] &, {dxy, 
   Array[Blend["Rainbow", #] &, Length@dxy, {0, 1}]}], 
 BoxRatios -> {2, 2, 1}, ImageSize -> 400]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
ClearAll[lnChrt];
lnChrt[dt_, w_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] :=
  ListPlot3D[(# /. {x_, y_, z_} :>Sequence[{x + w/2, y, z}, {x - w/2, y, z}])&/@dt, opts]

options = {Mesh -> None, Filling -> Axis, FillingStyle -> Opacity[.4],
        BoxRatios -> {3, 3, 2}, ImageSize -> 500}; 
lnChrt[dxy, 40, PlotStyle -> ColorData[1, "ColorList"], options]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

After version 12.3 (2021) `ListLinePlot3D` is available.

```
ListLinePlot3D[dxy
 , AxesLabel -> {"Distance", "Time", "Value"}
 , LabelStyle -> Directive[Bold]
 , Filling -> Axis
 , PlotLegends -> Placed[
   SwatchLegend[{"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"}]
   , After]
 , ImageSize -> 500
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: The `SwatchLegend` isn't visible

Comment: I have updated the image. Thanks.